# Cannot find `ViewController` in prepare for segue

Tags: swift, xcode

I´m trying to pass data from one `ViewController` to another. But when I try to set the destinationVC Xcode doesn't recognize the `ViewController`. I get no autocomplete for the `DataRecieverViewController` I get autocomplete for the other `ViewCOntrollers` When I write it in manually, I get no errors, but no data is passed.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == passDataSegue {

            let destination = segue.destination as! DataRecieverViewController    //Xcode doesn't recognize this VC. I get no autocomplete. 

destination.data1 = data1   
 }    
}
```

Comment: Is it a typo? Should it be `DataReceiverViewController`? Is the type defined in the same project or did you forget to import the proper library?

Comment: check your class name as `DataRecieverViewController ` not file name, Maybe you've described it different and you must use breakpoint in that line.

Comment: @elia Spot on! Thank you

Comment: @PerNil did it worked?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "identfiername") 
{
    let destination = segue.destination as! DataRecieverViewController    
     destination.data1 = data1  
}
```

}

for you the identifier name is passDataSegue, When you work with segues please cross check the `seguename` and `viewcontroller` name once more to avoid erorrs.

Answer (score 0):

About autocomplete try to save the file `DataRecieverViewController` and build your project it is a common bug of Xcode.

About data pass 
Are you sure you are getting to the right instance of `DataRecieverViewController`, not the general class?
Is it embedded in a `NavigationController` ot `UITabBarController` ? 
if Yes you have to get the right instance.

If embedded in `UITabBarController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == passDataSegue) 
{
   let tabBar = segue.destination as! UITabBarController
   let controller = tabBar.viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is DataRecieverViewController }) as? DataRecieverViewController
     controller.data1 = data1  
}
```

In case of `UINavigationController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == passDataSegue) 
{

   let NavBar = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
   let NavC = NavBar.viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is DataRecieverViewController }) as? DataRecieverViewController
let controller = NavC.rootViewController as? DataRecieverViewController
     controller.data1 = data1  
}
```